# Split MariaDB column into three different columns

Tags: mysql, split, mariadb, multiple-columns

I have a table loginData as

| col |
| --- |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01event_scheduler1 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01kaarmax1 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_adp_integration_scheduler7 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_appointment20 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_appointment_push2 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_arkona_integration_scheduler2 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_batchjobs47 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_billing10 |
| 2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_calender_bot9 |
| 2020-11-30 03:40:01mk_dms_adp_integration3 |
| 2020-11-30 03:42:01mk_dms_adp_integration3 |

I want to split the data into 3 different columns

| time_stamp | login | number_of_login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-30 03:42:01 | mk_dms_adp_integration | 3 |

the last integer can be longer than one digit, my question is different from other questions because it doesn't have delimiters

Thanks

Comment: Use [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/).

Comment: Could you please give an example I cannot seem to figure it out, how to split these into different colmns

Comment: `time_stamp` has fixed length and may be extracted by it using SUBSTRING(). `login` may be extracted using pattern `[a-z_]*`. `number_of_login` may be extracted using pattern `\d*$`.

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[a-z_]*','') AS text from logindata
this doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Let this be a lesson that the data should have been split up _before_ inserting.

Comment: this table was given to me as is, if I was the one inserting data I definitely would have taken care of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a particularly difficult problem so long as the first 19 digits of the text are always a full datetime stamp:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(tmp.`col`, 1, 19) AS DATETIME) as `dts`, SUBSTRING(tmp.`col`, 20) as `login`, COUNT(SUBSTRING(tmp.`col`, 1, 19)) as `number_of_login`
  FROM (SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01event_scheduler1' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01kaarmax1' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_adp_integration_scheduler7' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_appointment20' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_appointment20' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_appointment20' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_appointment20' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_arkona_integration_scheduler2' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_billing10' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_billing10' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:38:01mk_calender_bot9' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:40:01mk_dms_adp_integration3' as col UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2020-11-30 03:40:01mk_dms_adp_integration3' as col) tmp 
 GROUP BY `dts`, `login`;
```

I've modified some of your sample data to show different values in the `number_of_login` column.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
`ALTER TABLE tmp.data ADD COLUMN time_stamp TIMESTAMP NULL after col, ADD COLUMN logins VARCHAR(500) NULL after time_stamp, ADD COLUMN no_of_logins INT NULL after logins;`

Step 2

`update tmp.data  set time_stamp = left(tmp.data.col, 19), logins = REGEXP_REPLACE(tmp.data,'[0-9]|-|:',''), no_of_logins = REGEXP_REPLACE(substring(tmp.data.col,20),'[a-z]|_','')`

Probably not very efficient but this is what I used.